# 'UCS-2' codec can't encode characters in position 1050-1050

Tags: python, unicode, encoding, ucs2

When I run my Python code, I get the following errors:

```
  File "E:\python343\crawler.py", line 31, in <module>
    print (x1)
  File "E:\python343\lib\idlelib\PyShell.py", line 1347, in write
    return self.shell.write(s, self.tags)
UnicodeEncodeError: 'UCS-2' codec can't encode characters in position 1050-1050: Non-BMP character not supported in Tk
```

Here is my code:

```
x = g.request('search', {'q' : 'TaylorSwift', 'type' : 'page', 'limit' : 100})['data'][0]['id']

# GET ALL STATUS POST ON PARTICULAR PAGE(X=PAGE ID)
for x1 in g.get_connections(x, 'feed')['data']:
    print (x1)
    for x2 in x1:
        print (x2)
        if(x2[1]=='status'):
            x2['message']
```

How can I fix this?

Comment: if you need to see non-bmp Unicode characters; you could run python interactively in the environment that can show them e.g., in ConEmu console or a web browser. Try [ipython notebook](http://ipython.org/notebook.html).

Answer (score 31, accepted):

Your data contains characters outside of the [*Basic Multilingual Plane*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Plane_(Unicode)#Basic_Multilingual_Plane). Emoji's for example, are outside the BMP, and the window system used by IDLE, Tk, cannot handle such characters.

You could use a [translation table](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.translate) to map everything outside of the BMP to the [replacement character](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Specials_%28Unicode_block%29#Replacement_character):

```
import sys
non_bmp_map = dict.fromkeys(range(0x10000, sys.maxunicode + 1), 0xfffd)
print(x.translate(non_bmp_map))
```

The `non_bmp_map` maps all codepoints outside the BMP (any codepoint higher than 0xFFFF, all the way up to the [highest Unicode codepoint your Python version can handle](https://docs.python.org/3/library/sys.html#sys.maxunicode)) to [U+FFFD REPLACEMENT CHARACTER](https://codepoints.net/U+FFFD):

```
>>> print('This works outside IDLE! \U0001F44D')
This works outside IDLE! 
>>> print('This works in IDLE too! \U0001F44D'.translate(non_bmp_map))
This works in IDLE too! �
```

Comment: Thank you, but after add these, is shows new error: print (x1.translate(non_bmp_map))
AttributeError: 'dict' object has no attribute 'translate', so how to do it??

Comment: @Andi: `x1` is not a string, then, but a dictionary. You could do `str(x1).translate(non_bmp_map)` in that case.

Answer (score 4):

None of these worked for me but the following does.  This assumes that public_tweets was pulled from tweepy api.search

```
for tweet in public_tweets:
    print (tweet.text)
    u=tweet.text
    u=u.encode('unicode-escape').decode('utf-8')
```

Answer (score 4):

this unicode issue has been seen in python 3.6 and older versions, to resolve it just upgrade python as python 3.8 and use your code.This error will not come.

Comment: I'm glad to upvote your answer because 1) I find it very useful, 2) I am the very first to make you an upvote to welcome you on stackoverflow.