# Using if elif statements with Tweepy in Python

Tags: python-3.x, twitter, tweepy

I'm trying to create a bit of code to listen certain keywords on Twitter and am struggling to get the results I want.

I'm using Python 3.4.3.

Here's what I have that's working so far...

---

```
import tweepy
from time import sleep 
CONSUMER_KEY = 'abcabcabc'
CONSUMER_SECRET = 'abcabcabc'
ACCESS_KEY = 'abcabcabc'
ACCESS_SECRET = 'abcabcabc'
auth = tweepy.OAuthHandler(CONSUMER_KEY, CONSUMER_SECRET)
auth.set_access_token(ACCESS_KEY, ACCESS_SECRET)
auth.secure = True
api = tweepy.API(auth)

class MyStreamListener(tweepy.StreamListener):
    def on_status(self, status):
        try:
            print(status.text)
        except:
            print("false")

myStreamListener = MyStreamListener
myStream = tweepy.Stream(auth = api.auth, listener=myStreamListener())


myStream.filter(track=['Cycling', 'Running'])
```

---

I'm trying to an **if** and **elif** statements to print different results depending on if the Tweet is Cycling or Running.  I've used this code, but can't get it to work...

---

```
class MyStreamListener(tweepy.StreamListener):
    def on_status(self, status):
        if 'Cycling' in myStreamListener:
            print('Cyclist' + status.text)
        elif 'Running' in myStreamListener:
            print('Runner' + status.text)
        else:
            print('false' + status.text)

myStreamListener = MyStreamListener
myStream = tweepy.Stream(auth = api.auth, listener=myStreamListener())


myStream.filter(track=['Cycling', 'Running'])
```

---

I can get the **if** & **elif** to work offline when not adding the complexity of Tweepy into the equation, but am confused about exactly how to use the **in** statement.

I'm new to Python so will more than likely be making some simple mistakes!

Any help would be greatly appreciated,

Many thanks,

Matt

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are using `in` with the wrong variable (which points to the listener function). Use the `status` variable instead:

```
if 'cycling' in status.text.lower():
    print('Cyclist' + status.text)
```

Note that I added `.lower()` to the end of `status.text`. That way it will match the word 'cycling' regardless of if it is capitalised or not.

Comment: Thank you for your help.  The code worked and does what I wanted.  I seem to be getting a coding error now but will open a new thread if I can't solve it... UnicodeEncodeError: 'UCS-2' codec can't encode characters in position 69-69: Non-BMP character not supported in Tk

Comment: Regarding that error see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32442608/python-error-ucs-2-codec-cant-encode-characters-in-position-1050-1050