# How to exclude the characters which are not in the BMP in python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, utf-8, urllib

This is an app that gives a term and crawls [Urban Dictionary](https://www.urbandictionary.com) and returns the first meaning located in the page.
this is my code so far:

```
import re
import urllib.request

term = input('Enter a word: ')
url = "https://www.urbandictionary.com/define.php?term=" + term

rawData = urllib.request.urlopen(url).read()
decodedData = rawData.decode("utf-8")

x = re.search('div class="meaning"', rawData)
start = x.start()
end = x.end()
result = rawData[start:end]
print(result)
```

but I get the error below

```
    Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#8>", line 1, in <module>
    print(decodedData)
  File "~\Python\Python35-32\lib\idlelib\PyShell.py", line 1344, in write
    return self.shell.write(s, self.tags)
UnicodeEncodeError: 'UCS-2' codec can't encode characters in position 95889-95889: Non-BMP character not supported in Tk
```

how can I exclude the characters that can't be decoded?

Comment: On what line do you get the error? Please post the full traceback.

Comment: edited! @MegaIng

Comment: You are using idle, right?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32442608/ucs-2-codec-cant-encode-characters-in-position-1050-1050 can this help?

Comment: @MegaIng i tried both idle and a vscode python extension.

Comment: @Joe helped in some ways, thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK, to solve your problem, you just have to actually use your decoded data. Currently your are decoding your data, but then you use the `rawData`:

```
import re
import urllib.request

term = input('Enter a word: ')
url = "https://www.urbandictionary.com/define.php?term=" + term

rawData = urllib.request.urlopen(url).read()
decodedData = rawData.decode("utf-8")

x = re.search('div class="meaning"', decodedData)
start = x.start()
end = x.end()
result = decodedData[start:end]
print(result)
```

That should do it. If this doesn't work, please post an example word that throws this error. (This code will not produce the output you want by the way)

Comment: just realized the problem, opened this page to post the answer and saw this :) thx