# Python errors getting members list

Tags: python-3.x, discord.py

I am trying to get all of the member's list, everything works fine with below code but sometimes I get an error: `UnicodeEncodeError: 'UCS-2' codec can't encode characters in position 11-11: Non-BMP character not supported in Tk`

So how to ignore this and get members list.

```
server = bot.get_server(id="xxxxxxxxxxxx")
if server:
    for member in server.members:
        print('name: {}'.format(member.name) )
        print('id: {}'.format(member.id) )
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of ['UCS-2' codec can't encode characters in position 1050-1050](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32442608/ucs-2-codec-cant-encode-characters-in-position-1050-1050)

Comment: The problem is not in your code, IDLE can't display some of the characters.  You can remove those characters, or switch to a different way of running your code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use `try` and `except`.

The reason for the error is the encoding of the "members list", so try to use this:

```
server = bot.get_server(id="xxxxxxxxxxxx")
if server:
    for member in server.members:
        try:
            print('name: {}'.format(member.name) )
            print('id: {}'.format(member.id) )
        except UnicodeEncodeError:
            # do somthing
            pass
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: I already tried this but it stops code in middle but not continues remaining list again.

Comment: I have moved the `try` `except` into the for loop