# emoji not printing in python shows UnicodeEncodeError

Tags: python

I'm trying to print an emoji on Python

**Code:**

```
print("\U0001f600")
```

I'm trying to print using unicode but after compiling it shows error

**Error:**

> Traceback (most recent call last): File
>   "C:/Users/RAHUL/Desktop/new.py", line 1, in print("\U0001f600")
>   UnicodeEncodeError: 'UCS-2' codec can't encode character '\U0001f600'
>   in position 0: Non-BMP character not supported in Tk

I have searched on the internet but did't found the answer

Comment: Possible duplicate of ['UCS-2' codec can't encode characters in position 1050-1050](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32442608/ucs-2-codec-cant-encode-characters-in-position-1050-1050)

Comment: try puting  "# coding: utf-8" on top of your code

Comment: @colinrenaud still not working

Comment: try `print("\U0001f600".encode('usc-2'))`