# Unable to decode string to utf-8 in python

Tags: python, string, encoding, utf-8

i am trying to save strings that contain emojies to a .txt file, but I always get an error when running the code.

Code:

```
I set the .txt file up to have an utf-8 encoding.


subject_proper = subject.text.strip()
subject_proper = subject_proper.decode('utf-8')
```

Error:

```
subject_proper = subject_proper.decode('utf-8')
AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'decode'
```

Edit:

if i drop the .decode I get the following error:

```
UnicodeEncodeError: 'UCS-2' codec can't encode characters in position 65-65: Non-BMP character not supported in Tk
```

Edit 2:

Example text: Christmas treats for the triathletes ⛄

I have scraped the strings from https://milled.com/wiggle-co-uk

This method has worked before, but I dont know why it does not with this code. I have tried to find the answer elsewhere, but unfortunately without success.

I hope someone has an idea :)

Comment: This might just be the difference between Python 2 and Python 3.

Comment: Does this answer your question? ['str' object has no attribute 'decode'. Python 3 error?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28583565/str-object-has-no-attribute-decode-python-3-error)

Comment: Decode works on bytes. `b'some text'.decode('utf-8')` will work but `'some text'.decode('utf-8')` will not.

Comment: Perhaps try `subject_proper.encode('unicode-escape').decode('utf-8')` ? Found this answer which may be relevant: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32442608/ucs-2-codec-cant-encode-characters-in-position-1050-1050

Comment: I have given that a go and i get the following error: IndexError: string index out of range

Comment: Please consider adding some of the text you're trying to parse / decode to the question.

Comment: @WGriffing I have tried that as well. In this case it does work, but there are no more emjies in the document. Just the codes such as \xa340

Comment: I figured out what the problem was. The code runs in pycharm without issues, but does not in idle. Removing the print output to the console has fixed the issue. It is now printing to the .txt without issues.

Comment: Does this answer your question? ['UCS-2' codec can't encode characters in position 1050-1050](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32442608/ucs-2-codec-cant-encode-characters-in-position-1050-1050)

Answer (score 1):

[You're trying to decode a string that has already been decoded.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28583969/7431860) If your file is set to utf-8 but only has ASCII characters in it, I don't think the encoding matters.

Once you have a `str`, there's no need to decode it anymore. If you drop `.decode('utf-8')`, the error will likely go away.

If you're expecting code to possibly have utf-8 values, you can surround it with a `try-except` block to catch an `AttributeError`, and then act on it accordingly.

Comment: Unfortunatley that does not work. I get the following error: UnicodeEncodeError: 'UCS-2' codec can't encode characters in position 65-65: Non-BMP character not supported in Tk

Comment: Possibly consider `subject_proper =subject_proper .encode('unicode-escape').decode('utf-8')`? I'm not sure what characters you're trying to parse, but python doesn't seem to like them. Consider checking [this question out, too.](https://stackoverflow.com/q/32442608/7431860)